# Is $\mathbb C$ "exponentially algebraically closed"?

Tags: field-theory, exponential-function, model-theory

Is it known whether there is any term (with parameters) $t$ with exactly one free variable $x$ in the language of exponential fields such that $\forall x : t\neq 0$ in $\mathbb C$ but $\exists x : t=0$ in some exponential field extension of $\mathbb C$?

(There seems not to be an exponential-fields tag so i put the exponential-function tag, not sure if adequate).

Comment: The usual model-theoretic generalization of "algebraically closed" is "[existentially closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentially_closed_model)". It is known that $\mathbb{C}$ is not existentially closed in the class of exponential fields. But your condition is weaker, since you only consider existential formulas of the special form $\exists x\,(t = 0)$ for a term $t$ in one free variable. (Also: I assume you allow parameters from $\mathbb{C}$?) I don't know whether $\mathbb{C}$ is exponentially algebraically closed in your sense (which is why I"m writing a comment, not an answer).

Comment: @AlexKruckman When i thought about the question i didn't envision allowing parameters from $\mathbb C$. But an answer for that case would be interesting too.

Comment: If you don't allow parameters from the field, your condition isn't a generalization of "algebraically closed" at all. Consider the condition on a field $K$: For any term $t$ in the language of fields with exactly one free variable $x$, if $F\models \exists x\,(t = 0)$ for some field extension $K\subseteq F$, then $K\models \exists x\,(t =0)$. This condition just says that $K$ contains the algebraic closure of its prime field (not that $K$ is algebraically closed), since terms without parameters only describe polynomials over the prime field.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Actually forget that comment i was confusing things. Parameters should be allowed, i will update the question.